# Plant ID: Is this lemon balm?

Tags: identification, lemons

I found this growing in one of my pots.
[image]
Does this look like lemon balm? The leaves impart a very lemony smell when you touch them.

I looked online but the veins on a lemon balm leaf looks more pronounced. Could it be because the plant in the photo is very young?

Comment: Leaf shape and arrangement look like it, but you're right, the leaf texture, as yet, does not seem quite right, not textured enough... see how it looks as it gets bigger. If you're not going to make culinary use of it, it doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it has a square stem, then it is in the mint family. That includes Lemon Balm. If it smells like lemons I would assume it's Lemon Balm.